# SQL - HAVING Clause in depth

Tags: sql, having-clause

I'm trying to understand what condition can be placed after the having clause - it is usually a condition, that uses the functions from the select statement, but it also can contain a column, that is typed in the select statement.

Here's an example:

```
create table r(a int, b int, c int, d int, e int primary key)

select a, min(b), sum(c)
from r
where b > 5
group by a
having "condition"
```

which of the following can replace the "condition"

```
a) b = 5

b) a = sum(e)

c) min(b) >= 6
```

When I execute this in SQL, only a) doesn't work, but what's the logic behind it?

Comment: The HAVING clause is for aggregate function conditions.

Comment: @Nithin, not everywhere.

Comment: The HAVING clause was added to SQL because the WHERE keyword could not be used with aggregate functions. Reference https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp  Hence the case a  will not work as that is not aggregate function

Comment: HAVING filters to eliminate the results of an aggregated group, the expression `b = 5` is not valid because `b` is not aggregated or grouped.

Comment: ok, it think it is clearer now - for example a = 2 works, because we're grouping by a

Answer (score 0):

This will be correct one

```
create table r(a int, b int, c int, d int, e int primary key)

select a, min(b), sum(c)
from r
where b > 5
group by a
having "min(b) >= 6"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `HAVING` clause is applied as a filter after the `GROUP BY`.

If you keep that in mind, it becomes obvious that:

`b=5` fails because you don't `GROUP BY b` in the query and `b` is used as-is and not in an aggregation function.

`a=SUM(e)` succeeds because you `GROUP BY a` and compare `a` with an aggregate function.

`MIN(b) >= 6` succeeds because you compare an aggregate function with a constant.

Hope this clarifies ...